# Deserialize JSON to Object

Tags: python, json, deserialization

I'm working on a trivial problem here to deserialize some JSON (I cannot change the format, it's not a service I created) into Python objects. I've managed to do the conversion using lambda's, but I'd like to use an object_hook now, to see if the it's possible to do a conversion using the `json.loads` method. However, that's where I'm failing right now, and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import json

class Light:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

response = '{"1": {"name": "bedroom"}, "2": {"name": "kitchen"}}'

def object_decoder(obj):
    return Light(......)

print json.loads(response, object_hook=object_decoder)
```

As you can see, the `response` is one document with two keys, named 1 and 2. It would be nice if I can make the the code work in a way that the `json.loads` would return two Light objects, but at the moment, I'm stuck, and I don't know how to iterate over response to make this work.

Comment: Remember that your object_decoder can return an iterator. Use yield

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`object_hook` won't help you, since you have `id` and `name` on the different levels in the json string:

> object_hook, if specified, will be called with the result of every
>   JSON object decoded and its return value will be used in place of the
>   given dict.

Let's see why `object_hook` won't help. If you print objects that are coming to the `object_decoder` function, you'll see that it is going up from the deep, like this:

```
{u'name': u'bedroom'}
{u'name': u'kitchen'}
{u'1': None, u'2': None}
None
```

This means that you cannot join `object_decoder` calls in order to produce a `Light` instance.

How about using custom [JSONDecoder](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) class instead:

```
import json


class Light:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name


response = '{"1": {"name": "bedroom"}, "2": {"name": "kitchen"}}'


class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def decode(self, s):
        obj = super(Decoder, self).decode(s)
        return [Light(id=k, name=v['name']) for k, v in obj.iteritems()]


lights = json.loads(response, cls=Decoder)
print lights  # prints [<__main__.Light instance at 0x9c3b50c>, <__main__.Light instance at 0x9c3b56c>]
print [light.__dict__ for light in lights]  # prints [{'id': u'1', 'name': u'bedroom'}, {'id': u'2', 'name': u'kitchen'}]
```

This is actually the same as making `json.loads()` and then instantiate classes after.

Comment: To match the input, shouldn't `decode()` return a dictionary object with two items in it rather than a `list` of the two items?

Comment: @martineau well, the OP wants `json.loads` to return two `Light` instances..I understand that the method I've suggested is pretty much the same as make usual `json.loads()` and then make a list of `Light` instances from it.

Comment: The Python docs say `json.load()` and `loads()` deserialize a _JSON document_ into a Python object without defining the term. Nor is it defined by the [format's website](http://www.json.org/). However other references I've found say a it's either an ordered list or a unordered key/value mapping (which the docs call a JSON _object_). In the OP's question the sample input looks like the latter, so I'd expect the `Decoder.decode()` method to return a Python dictionary from it.

Comment: In a nutshell, I think the `decode()` method should end with `return {k: Light(id, name) for k, v in obj.iteritems() for id, name in v.iteritems()}`. This will result in a dictionary containing something like `{u'1': <__main__.Light instance at 0x00BB2E90>, u'2': <__main__.Light instance at 0x00BB2D50>}`. Note: I'm still up-voting this answer.

Comment: Thanks! I haven' tried this, but I'm pretty sure this wil work! Thanks for your elaborate example!

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the format of the string, I suggest you use [jsonpickle](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle). I've founded it perfect for this sort of thing.

Comment: Won't work since the format of the string is not changeable by the OP.